# Insert into existing table from another using a where from the first - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

In SQL Server is it possible to insert data into an existing table from another table, using a where that involves data from the table you are inserting into?

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO TableOne (somethingFromTable2ButInTable1)
(SELECT somethingFromTable2 FROM Table2
WHERE Table2.somethingElse = Table1.SomethingElse)
```

I've tried the syntax I can think of but it doesn't work.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TableOne (somethingFromTable2ButInTable1)
SELECT T2.somethingFromTable2 
FROM Table2 T2 
join TableOne T1
WHERE T2.somethingElse = T1.SomethingElse
and T2.somethingFromTable2 is not null
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me sadly.  I get an error about not inserting nulls into a column I'm not even trying to insert into.